# Can't get Google Login and Facebook login to work together, they work separately

Tags: php, facebook, oauth, oauth-2.0

As the title says, I can't get the two to work together.

The two work perfectly on their own, but when both are included and I try to log in with Facebook, I get this error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'apiAuthException' with message 'Error fetching OAuth2 access token, message: 'invalid_grant'' in /home/a801/public_html/Assignment_v2/google-api-php-client/src/auth/apiOAuth2.php:105 Stack trace: #0 /home/a801/public_html/Assignment_v2/google-api-php-client/src/apiClient.php(138): apiOAuth2->authenticate(Array) #1 /home/a801/public_html/Assignment_v2/googlelogin.php(38): apiClient->authenticate() #2 /home/a3422801/public_html/Assignment_v2/index.php(4): require('/home/a801/...') #3 {main} thrown in /home/a801/public_html/Assignment_v2/google-api-php-client/src/auth/apiOAuth2.php on line 105

As far as I'm concerned, the Facebook login shouldn't be going anywhere near that code, that's the code that's used for the Google login.

I'll gladly provide any code you think might be needed to sort out this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Google Login and Facebook login are completely independant. It's not hard to make them work once you understand the basics.

Check this out, i've used some of the code for a project of my own. It's really easy to understand.

[Hybridauth](http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/)

Cheers